# Problem with onRenderOption error in fluentUI dropdown

Tags: dropdown, react-typescript

const SearchableDropdownComponent: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

```
    function renderOption(option: IDropdownOption): JSX.Element {
      return (option.itemType === DropdownMenuItemType.Header && option.key === "FilterHeader") ?
        <SearchBox onChange={(ev, newValue: any) => setSearchText(newValue)} underlined={true} placeholder="Search options" />: <>{option.text}</>;
    }
  
    return (
      <Dropdown
        {...props}
        options={[
          { key: 'FilterHeader', text: '-', itemType: DropdownMenuItemType.Header },
          { key: 'divider_filterHeader', text: '-', itemType: DropdownMenuItemType.Divider },
          ...props.options.map((option)  => !option.disabled && option.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1 ?
            option : { ...option, hidden: true }
          ),
        ]}
        calloutProps={{ shouldRestoreFocus: false, setInitialFocus: false }} //not working
        onRenderOption={renderOption}
        onDismiss={() => setSearchText('')}
      />
    );
  
  };
```

Comment: Here is the error when you hover on underlining onRenderOption:

Type '() => (option: IDropdownOption<any>) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'IRenderFunction<ISelectableOption<any>>'.
  Type '(option: IDropdownOption<any>) => Element' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, keyts(2322)
SelectableDroppableText.types.d.ts(75, 5): The expected type comes from property 'onRenderOption' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IDropdownProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error, and I fixed it by making the parameter 'option' optional.

```
function renderOption(option?: IDropdownOption ): JSX.Element {
  return option!.itemType === DropdownMenuItemType.Header &&
    option!.key === "FilterHeader" ? (
    <SearchBox
      onChange={(ev, newValue) => setSearchText(newValue ?? "")}
      underlined={true}
      placeholder="Search options"
    />
  ) : (
    <>{option!.text}</>
  );
```

}